# How to allow clicks to affect an element in addition to the elements below it?

Tags: html, onclick, click, onclicklistener, pointer-events

I know that the CSS `pointer-events: none;` makes elements beneath clickable.  But it disables clicks on the top element.

How can I have a single click affect the entire "stack" of elements?

Or at least, the element in question, as well as the element immediately below it.

I did a lot of searching but it seems everyone asking about clicking through elements, is not interested in having the top element recognize the click also.

Comment: A lazy approach will be to chain the onclick event using JS. So, if the top element on the stack is clicked you can set onclick event to for the top element to perform click on the second element, and for second element you can set on click event to click on thrid element and so on.......

Comment: That is what I will resort to in absence of a better answer.

Comment: Try setting pointer-events: inherit to child elements.